# POwerShell Glogal Hash how to 'echo'?

Tags: powershell, hash

I have defined a global hash

```
  $State = @{ "SeqNum" = 1 }
```

I need to check this in a function an access this value:

```
function check { param([int] $n)
# ...
   if ( $Global:State.SeqNum -ne $n ) {
      echo "FAILED: $Global:State.SeqNum != $n"
}
# ...
```

The print out to the console does not work :(
I get System.Collections.Hashtable.RmMsgNum instead on the vales of the key.

What do I have to do?

Thanks in advance,
Gooly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try evaluating it within string:

```
echo "FAILED: $($Global:State.SeqNum) != $n"
```